# What is the fastest way to rotate a jpg image file?

Tags: image, algorithm, delphi, delphi-xe2, jpeg

I am working on some batch routines to manage large libraries of jpg files.  I have a nice routine that will quickly downsize 4mb+ files down to 40kb+.  Using [CCR.Exif](http://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2012/01/16/xe2-update-for-my-image-metadata-readingwriting-library-ccr-exif/), I can determine if an image needs to be rotated.  My problem is that I can't find any code to rotate the image before I save it.  I really need to be able to do this without incurring the overhead of bringing the image to screen.

I'm using the built-in jpeg.pas; I found another library by Gabriel Corneanu at [CodeCentral](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/19723), but it hasn't been updated for DXE2.  All I need to do is a 90° rotation.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What class are you using for your JPG manipulation ? The built-in one from `jpeg.pas` unit ? How do you need to rotate you image ? By a 90° multiples or a free rotate by an arbitrary angle ?

Comment: I clarified the details; let me know if you need any more information.  Thanks for your interest!

Comment: So your actual question is "How do I rotate a JPEG image"? And please don't put tag information in the question title; SO has a great tag system that actually works, and it's unnecessary - people who watch for Delphi questions will be watching the tag, and people who don't care about them don't read them. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite - no. His actual question is rotating JPEGs at 90-degree step. That is not a full-blown rotation but just a header property toggling. Okay, much more than it but still much less than really freeform unpackign and rotating.

Comment: @Arioch'The: The question says "I can't find any code to rotate the image", and "All I need to do is a 90° rotation". The first sentence I quoted is the question, which is why I asked; the second is a qualification of that first sentence. Thanks, though.

Comment: The JPEG library has the image transformation support. Unfortunately it's not implemented in the jpeg.pas. However you may try to include it into your own jpeg library. Try to inspire from one FreePascal package; here is the [`transupp`](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fidB893A4299376B6F3F3DAA8B1509E3B1D1320AA43.aspx#L458) translation and the command line [`program`](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid244A1272232F535B63D0EB4B2C7FD0C38C7E26DF.aspx?s=jpeg#L1) showing the usage. It would be the most natural implementation you can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPGs are compressed and must be rendered before you can work with the image data.  Even if it is a non-visible canvas, they still need to be loaded into a component that renders them.  Then you can use Windows API calls to rotate the image by directly accessing the canvas.  I haven't *rotated* the image before, but I have manipulated it in other ways by accessing the canvas.

GR32 and EFG are both good sites with several components and algorithms.  Here is one example on EFG's site that rotates an image.  The code is Delphi 3, but it should still work fine for image manipulation.

[EFG Example with Source](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/ImageProcessing/FlipReverseRotate.htm)

`TImage32` has a method to rotate the image 90 degrees as well.  See `TImage32.Bitmap.Rotate90`.  `TImage32` is part of the GR32 library and has been updated for Delphi-XE2.

```
svn co https://graphics32.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/graphics32/trunk graphics32
```

Also see: [GR32 Homepage](http://graphics32.org/wiki/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the efg page!  That's where I found [link](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/ImageProcessing/Unit7.TXT) which does exactly what I needed.

And my apologies for the delay in accepting your answer.  I've been somewhat/extremely distracted lately.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to rotate JPEG in steps by 90 degree, then look for lossless transformations.
For example irfanview.com has a special plugin DLL for it, though it does not have public API, but maybe you can ask Irfan Author for it or reverse-engineer it with debugger and cff explorer.

a lot of discussion might by just googled, including discussion how it is implemented.
https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&q=lossless+jpeg+rotation

Component catalogues have that like
http://www.torry.net/quicksearchd.php?String=jpeg+lossless&Title=No

That will not work with rotation finer than 90 degree steps, but for orthogonal turns keep searchign for lossless jpeg transformations.

Comment: intel used to provide an imaging dll that had a great lossless jpeg rotation in it.

Comment: 1st google link discusses Independent JPEG Group, and their DLL with Delphi interface (even if obsoleted, that intf can probably be easy done with FreePascal's h2pas or manually since he only needs very few functions)

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to rotate a JPEG image would be to write a new / alternate pixel pump for the JPEG decoder that reads and decodes the JPEG pixels left to right (x,y), and writes them to bitmap memory as (y,x) - that is, writing one pixel per scanline at the same offset, instead of the normal mode of writing one pixel per column on the same scanline.

Anything else will be making multiple passes over the bitmap data.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Sounds interesting, but a bit over my capabilities at this point.